# GDB is off by a line when debugging a nasm application

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, nasm

I just encountered a weird issue with `gdb`, though I'm not sure, if I'm missing something.
Let's suppose I have these two files:

`somefile.asm`:

```
01 section .text
02 
03 funca:
04  mov eax, 5
05  mov ebx, 5
06  cmp eax, ebx
07  je aisequal
08  mov ecx, 13
09  mov edx, 19
10  ret
11
12  aisequal:
13  mov ecx, 17
14  mov edx, 21
15  ret
```

and
`somefile_test.asm`:

```
01 %include "somefile.asm"
02
03 section .text
04  global _start
05
06 _start:
07  xor eax, eax
08  xor ebx, ebx
09  xor ecx, ecx
10  xor edx, edx
11  call funca
12
13  mov eax, 1
14  mov ebx, 0
15  int 0x80
```

I compile and link it using

```
nasm -f elf -g -F dwarf somefile_test.asm 
ld -m elf_i386 -o somefile_test.out somefile_test.o
```

And then debug my application using `gdb`:

```
gdb somefile_test.out
```

I now set a breakpoint in the imported file:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 10.1
(gdb) b somefile.asm:5
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8049000: file somefile.asm, line 5.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /<bla>/somefile_test.out

Breakpoint , funca () at somefile.asm:5
5       mov ebx, 5
```

Now appearantly, the execution stopped at the correct position. The next line to be executed would be 5, which is `mov ebx, 5`.
**However**, the last line should've been `mov eax, 5` which should have already been executed. It was not:

```
(gdb) i r eax
eax            0x0                 0
```

It gets even weirder:

```
(gdb) si
6       cmp eax, ebx
(gdb) i r eax ebx
eax            0x5                 5
ebx            0x0                 0
```

Now, `eax` is set, but `ebx` is not (yet).
If I execute the next line, it is set:

```
(gdb) si
7       je aisequal
(gdb) i r eax ebx
eax            0x5                 5
ebx            0x5                 5
```

However, I'd expect the program to jump to line 12 (aisequal) now, but it doesn't:

```
(gdb) si
8       mov ecx, 13
```

On the next instruction, it suddenly goes to the right line:

```
(gdb) si
14      mov edx, 21
(gdb) i r eax ebx edx
eax            0x5                 5
ebx            0x5                 5
edx            0x0                 0
```

And so on:

```
(gdb) si
15      ret
(gdb) i r eax ebx ecx edx
eax            0x5                 5
ebx            0x5                 5
ecx            0x11                17
edx            0x0                 0
```

If I put all my code in a single file, everything works as expected:

```
01 section .text
02  global _start
03
04 _start:
05  xor eax, eax
06  xor ebx, ebx
07  xor ecx, ecx
08  xor edx, edx
09  call funca
10
11  mov eax, 1
12  mov ebx, 0
13  int 0x80
14
15 funca:
16  mov eax, 5
17  mov ebx, 5
18  cmp eax, ebx
19  je aisequal
20  mov ecx, 13
21  mov edx, 19
22  ret
23
24  aisequal:
25  mov ecx, 17
26  mov edx, 21
27  ret
```

```
GBU gdb (GDB) 10.1
(gdb) b 16
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8049019: file singlefile.asm, line 16.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /<bla>/singlefile.out 

Breakpoint 1, funca () at singlefile.asm:16
16      mov eax, 5
(gdb) i r eax ebx ecx edx
eax            0x0                 0
ebx            0x0                 0
ecx            0x0                 0
edx            0x0                 0
(gdb) si
17      mov ebx, 5
(gdb) i r eax ebx ecx edx
eax            0x5                 5
ebx            0x0                 0
ecx            0x0                 0
edx            0x0                 0
(gdb) si
18      cmp eax, ebx
(gdb) si
19      je aisequal
(gdb) si
25      mov ecx, 17
(gdb) si
26      mov edx, 21
(gdb) i r eax ebx ecx edx
eax            0x5                 5
ebx            0x5                 5
ecx            0x11                17
edx            0x0                 0
(gdb) si
aisequal () at singlefile.asm:27
27      ret
(gdb) i r eax ebx ecx edx
eax            0x5                 5
ebx            0x5                 5
ecx            0x11                17
edx            0x15                21
(gdb) si
_start () at singlefile.asm:11
11      mov eax, 1
```

Now I've only picked up `gdb` two days ago, so I'm not that familiar with it.
Can someone explain to me what's happening?
Is this a bug or am I missing something?

I am using

```
nasm 2.15.05-1
binutils 2.35.1-1
gdb 10.1-4
gcc 10.2.0-4
```

on `Linux 5.9.14-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat, 12 Dec 2020 14:37:12 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: As a workaround, you can use `display/i $pc` to have gdb always disassemble the next instruction to be executed.  For assembly programs this is often just as good as the source line.  You will probably want to `set disassembly-flavor intel`.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Or `layout asm` to show disassembly in a TUI window, ignoring the source file.  (Recent GDB seems to have made `layout reg` do registers + source layout, not regs + asm, so I've needed `layout next` a couple times to fix it; really annoying especially if the source uses macros so source lines aren't 1:1 with instructions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in `nasm`. It didn't reproduce for me using `nasm-2.14`.

GDB will only display source info that the compiler/assembler tells it. If the assembler puts out incorrect info, then GDB will display that incorrect info and can't do anything about it.

To verify that the problem is in `nasm`, run `objdump -dS somefile_test.o` and compare the assembly and source listing. If they are also off by one, it's a bug in `nasm`.

Here is what I see:

```
somefile_test.o:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <funca>:
section .text

funca:
 mov eax, 5
   0:   b8 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%eax
 mov ebx, 5
   5:   bb 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%ebx
 cmp eax, ebx
   a:   39 d8                   cmp    %ebx,%eax
 je aisequal
   c:   74 0b                   je     19 <aisequal>
```

Note how instructions and source perfectly line up.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this is a [regression](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=27118#c4) in nasm.

[Reported](https://bugzilla.nasm.us/show_bug.cgi?id=3392731) it to them.